# windows上のゲストOSに別pc(mac)からsamba接続できない

Tags: virtualbox, samba

こんにちは。
windows上にvirutalboxでcentos7を立てました。
このゲストOSにwindowsと同じLAN内にある別PC(mac)からsamba接続したいと思っています。

### （１）やったこと。

（１−１）virtualboxでポートフォワーディングの設定
ホストOSのIPアドレス 192.168.0.7
ホストポート 44445
ゲストIP　192.168.56.101
ゲストポート 445

（１−２）ゲストOS側でselinux、firewalldの設定は疎通確認のため、無効

ここでmacのFinderからsmb://192.168.0.7:44445で接続を試みたのですが、接続できませんでした。なぜ接続できないのか、ご指摘いただけたら幸いです。

### （２）確認できていること

（２−１）ホストOSからゲストOSへは192.168.56.101への　samba接続はできた
（２−２）smb.confで特にIP制限はしていない
（２−３）別PC(mac)でtelnet(192.168.0.7 44445)を試みて、connectedにはなった。

Comment: CentOS 7 の /var/log/samba/ 以下に何か失敗の原因となるログは出力されていないでしょうか。

Comment: 調べてみたところ、STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsDenied connection from 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2)というエラーが確認できました

Comment: 仮想マシンのネットワークアダプタの設定を教えてくださいますか。アダプタがいくつ合って、NAT、ホストオンリーなどの設定がどうなってるか知りたいです。あと接続できないのはsambaだけでしょうか。sshなどの他のポートはフォワーディング出来てるか、もし確認できれば教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.0.2.2 がおそらく mac だと思いますが、smb.conf の hosts allow で許可されていないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: hosts.allowの設定を見直しましたら、接続することができました。
みなさまお騒がせしました。

Comment: @user3321541 解決したのでしたら、回答左側のチェックマークをクリックして、承認マークをつけてください。質問が解決済みとわかりますし、回答者に信用度のボー‌​ナスも与えられます。 詳細はこちら→ http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/8000